# How to get value from programmatically added UC on StackPanel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

SO here is my **UC**

```
 public partial class ChartDialogView : UserControl
    {
      public long Value
        {
         get
           {
              return TextBox1.Content;
           }
        }
        public ChartDialogView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

And on main form i add some this **UC** items

```
ChartDialogView uc = new ChartDialogView();
            ChartList.Children.Add(uc);
```

So question is how to get value of second(for example) added item?
this is my XAML(maybe it helps)

```
            <ScrollViewer Margin="44,40,0,11"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                          Width="257"
                          Foreground="{x:Null}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="ChartList">
                    <StackPanel.ScrollOwner>
                        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" />
                    </StackPanel.ScrollOwner>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

[All of that look like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEbX1.png)

Comment: The same way you added the User Controls. By accessing `Chartlist.Children[1]`.

Comment: its good but i steel cant access to values of this UC cuz this UC added dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the way if some one need

```
foreach (ChartDialogView setInformation in ChartList.Children.OfType<ChartDialogView>())
            {
                string txt1 = setInformation.Name.Content.ToString() ;
                MessageBox.Show(txt1);
            }
```